# Нужно из массива А все положительные элементы скопировать в массив B и найти в каждом массиве среднее арифметическое элементов

Tags: c

господа
Проходим сейчас динамическую память,и все не выходит нормально допилить прогу.Пока только дошел до того,чтобы положительные числа записывались во второй массив по порядку,а не аналогично своему номеру из первого массива,то бишь так

первый массив(1 -1 -3 4 5)  => второй массив(1 4 5  -858993460  -858993460  -858993460)

И дальше такие значения.Это,так понимаю,выделенная память,но так,как элементов меньше,то она пустеет и выводит (адрес?)
Подскажите,пожалуйста,как убрать ненужную память и сделать по уму программу,которая использует динамические массивы ,буду благодарен

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#define M 100


int main(int argc,char** argv) {
    system("chcp 1251 >> NUL");
    //srand(time(NULL));
    int arr1[M], arr2[M],k=NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        arr1[i] = 100 - rand() % 201;
        //printf("%i\n", arr1[i]);
        if (arr1[i] > 0) 
        {

            arr2[k] = arr1[i];
            k++;
            //printf("%i\n",arr2[i]);

        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        printf("%i              %i\n", arr1[i], arr2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: #include <malloc.h> зачем он Вам?

Comment: linux или win?&

Comment: win  на СИ
а <malloc.h> думал,что он нужен для функции maloc ,думал дин.массив через него сделать как-то,но не вышло

Comment: И то что Вам выводится это не адрес (адрес в hex формате) это просто машинный мусор.

Answer (score 0):

Перед тем как преступить к решению любой задачи - планируйте и описывайте архитектуру Вашего решения, это позволит Вам быстро и легко все написать )
Порядок решения

1) выделение памяти под основной массив и обнуление памяти

2) Заполнение это данными результатом работы функции x(t) (rand())

3) поиск кол-ва положительных элементов (для выделения памяти под новый массив)

4) выделение памяти под новый массив и обнуление памяти

5) сохранение положительных значение под новый массив

6) вывод результата

7) освобождение памяти

Вот пример кода:
Обратите внимание на проверки при работе с дин памятью. Я добавил пару бональных проверок т.к. при работе с пямятью один не точный шаг  и бобо)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>


int GetCountOfPos(int* arr, const unsigned int size)
{
    if (!arr)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int cout_of_pos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] >= 0) {
            ++cout_of_pos;
        }
    }

    return cout_of_pos;
}


void SetRandValue(int* arr, const unsigned int size)
{
    if (!arr)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        arr[i] = rand()%RAND_MAX - RAND_MAX / 2;
    }
}

void CopyPosNum(int* arr, unsigned int size_1, int* pos_arr, unsigned int size_2)
{
    if (!arr)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (!pos_arr)
    {
        return;
    }
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size_1; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] >= 0)
        {
            pos_arr[k] = arr[i];
            ++k;
        }
        if (k >= size_2) {
            return;
        }
    }    

}

void PrintArray(int* arr, unsigned int size)
{
    if (!arr)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    const unsigned int size = 1000000;
    int* arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    if (!arr) {
        return -1;
    }
    memset(arr, size, 0);

    SetRandValue(arr, size);

    unsigned int c_pos = GetCountOfPos(arr, size);
    if (c_pos < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    int* pos_arr = malloc(c_pos * sizeof(int));
    if (!pos_arr) {
        return -1;
    }
    memset(pos_arr, c_pos, 0);

    CopyPosNum(arr, size, pos_arr, c_pos);

    PrintArray(pos_arr, c_pos);

    printf("pos value = %d\n", c_pos);

    if (arr) {
        free(arr);
    }
    if (pos_arr) {
        free(pos_arr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Среднее я думаю вы легко найдете.